# VBA SQL - Changing code from 'Insert Into' to 'Update' table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, sql-update, sql-insert

I have looked and looked for an answer and cannot translate the answers to my specific code. I have some code for an Access Database that works as an INSERT TO but I want it to UPDATE a table. I cannot get it to run after changing it to UPDATE.

The following code works and what it does is add values that meet the criteria to the beginning of an existing table. But I want it to update the existing blank column "O_StateRegion" in a table called "Sonoco2016_xlsx". My efforts of switching INSERT INTO to UPDATE have failed. (See second example of code for my efforts)

```
Private Sub InsertStateRegion()

On Error GoTo InsertRegions_Err

Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Select [OriginState] from [Sonoco2016_xlsx];")

rs.MoveFirst
While Not rs.EOF

    strSQL = "UPDATE [Sonoco2016_xlsx] ([O_StateRegion])"
    strSQL = strSQL & " SELECT [StateRegion] FROM [tblStates]"
    strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE [tblStates].[StateAbbrev]='" & rs![OriginState] & "' "

    db.Execute (strSQL), dbFailOnError

rs.MoveNext
Wend
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

btnInsertRegions_Exit:
    Exit Sub

InsertRegions_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description & " in btnInsertRegions"
    Resume btnInsertRegions_Exit

End Sub
```

Below are my efforts to convert it to UPDATE

```
Private Sub btnInsertRegions_Click()

On Error GoTo InsertRegions_Err

Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Select [OriginState] from [Sonoco2016_xlsx];")

rs.MoveFirst
While Not rs.EOF

    strSQL = "UPDATE [Sonoco2016_xlsx] ([O_StateRegion])"
    strSQL = strSQL & " SET [Sonoco2016_xlsx].[O_StateRegion]=[tblStates].[StateRegion]"
    strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE [tblStates].[StateAbbrev] = '" & rs![OriginState] & "' "

    db.Execute (strSQL), dbFailOnError

rs.MoveNext
Wend
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

btnInsertRegions_Exit:
    Exit Sub

InsertRegions_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description & " in btnInsertRegions"
    Resume btnInsertRegions_Exit

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you expand on why your form can't handle this natively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for what you want to achieve is

```
UPDATE [Sonoco2016_xlsx] 
    INNER JOIN [tblStates]
        ON [tblStates].[StateAbbrev] = [Sonoco2016_xlsx].[OriginState]
SET [Sonoco2016_xlsx].[O_StateRegion]=[tblStates].[StateRegion];
```

which you would execute without using a recordset.

Note, however, that this will only work if `[StateAbbrev]` has a unique index, e.g. if it is the primary key of `[tblStates]`. Otherwise, the update would be ambiguous.

Moreover, it is not possible to use a subquery in the set statement like

```
SET [Sonoco2016_xlsx].[O_StateRegion]=(SELECT [StateRegion] 
                                       FROM = [tblStates] 
                                       WHERE [StateAbbrev] = rs![OriginState])
```

because subqueries are prohibited in `UPDATE` statements.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! [State Region] is not a the primary key since multiple states can be in the same region of the country.

Comment: I hit enter too early. Thank you very much for your response! [State Region] is not a the primary key since multiple states can be in the same region of the country.  The code is designed to look the table [Sonoco2016_xlsx] for states, look for a matching state abbreviation in [tblStates] and return the [StateRegion] for the corresponding state into the [O_StateRegion] field in [Sonoco2016_xlsx] table. The code will run after the user imports an excel file into Access as a table. In this case, the imported table is [Sonoco2016_xlsx]

Comment: Sorry, there was a small mistake in my answer that I  corrected right now. I meant `[StateAbbrev]` not `[StateRegion]`.

Comment: Thank you M. Doerner! I went ahead and updated my code with your edits. I made it look like below and it ran great and put the appropriate states in the appropriate fields. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer that worked for me thanks to M Doerner!

```
Private Sub btnInsertRegions_Click()

On Error GoTo InsertRegions_Err

Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Select [OriginState] from [Sonoco2016_xlsx];")

rs.MoveFirst
While Not rs.EOF

    strSQL = "UPDATE [Sonoco2016_xlsx] INNER JOIN [tblStates]"
    strSQL = strSQL & " ON [tblStates].[StateAbbrev] = [Sonoco2016_xlsx].[OriginState]"
    strSQL = strSQL & " SET [Sonoco2016_xlsx].[O_StateRegion]=[tblStates].[StateRegion]"


    db.Execute (strSQL), dbFailOnError

rs.MoveNext
Wend
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

btnInsertRegions_Exit:
    Exit Sub

InsertRegions_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description & " in btnInsertRegions"
    Resume btnInsertRegions_Exit

End Sub
```